# clear browser cache after deployment

Tags: spring-mvc, deployment, browser-cache

Hi I am working on Spring MVC application
I have this requirement to clear browser cache or at least prompt user to clear it after every deployment on server
The server I am using is websphere
I am not using any cookies in my application
I am using jsp and not using any versioning on my js files

Can someone please help me on 
How can I detect new deployment on server?
I want to prompt user only first time after login when new deployment is detected for all browsers

Comment: you can try to use application initialization listener, and cookies, and checksum-maven-plugin.
I also trying to find some better solution now